# I want current week data

Tags: mysql

I want current week data from  mysql but problem is my field is varchar how i get the data

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) IS NULL' at line 3

```
SELECT `E`.`event_id`
FROM (`tbl_events` as E)
WHERE YEARWEEK(date_format(str_to_date(E.event_end,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')),YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have an extra `)` before the 2nd `yearweek()` call, which should go at the end of the expression. Syntax wise.

However, I think you are overcomplicating this a bit:

```
SELECT `E`.`event_id`
FROM (`tbl_events` as E)
WHERE YEARWEEK(str_to_date(E.event_end,'%m-%d-%Y'))=yearweek(curdate())
```

On the left hand side of the expression I get the week of the year from the record. This should equal to the week of the year for the current week, which is on the right hand side of the expression.